# How to recognize translatable strings by xgettext in PHP Arrays or DocBlocks (without method calls)?

Tags: php, gettext, poedit, xgettext

I'm using poEdit with the xgettext-Parser to parse my PHP source files and detect all translatable strings. By default, xgettext only recognizes strings in function calls like `translate("foo")`,
if "translate" is specified as a keyword for xgettext.

Now I have some translatable strings in PHP-arrays, like

```
array(
    'label' => 'foo',
);
```

or DocBlocks like

```
/**
 * @FormElement(type="text", options={
 *     "label"="Foobar",
 * })
 */
```

How can I manage to recognize these translatable strings "foo" or "Foobar" with xgettext?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @OytunTez See my suggestion in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dummy translate method, and use that when you create your array:

```
function dummy_translate ($string)
{
    return $string;
}

$array = array
(
    'label' => dummy_translate('foo')
);
```

And extract with:

```
xgettext --keyword=dummy_translate:1
```

Also as your xgettext keywords must *form a valid C identifier*, you cannot do this, just before the array:

```
$dummy_method = function ($string)
{
    return $string;
}
```

Just find a good place to put your dummy method.

Did not use DocBlocks for more than documentations, so not sure about that, but I guess a similar approach should work there to.

*P.S. The performance of the extra function call is negligible, please don't waste time with micro-optimizations*.